# Difference between "If a" and "If any"

Tags: grammar

I have provided some sentences below. What's the difference between "if a" and "if any" in the sentences. I think all of them are correct and mean the same thing. I don't know what the difference is. I always use them interchangeably in this kind of context. Can someone please tell me how I should choose the correct word?

1- If ***a/any*** student is found smoking in the classroom, he or she will be suspended from the school.

2- As per the new tax law, If ***a/any*** house is situated in a metropolitan city, 15 percent tax will be charged on the value of it.

Comment: It seems to me that in each of those examples, there's no change in meaning if we replace "a" with "any," and no change in formality or correctness.

Comment: In your examples, I'd write "if any student" but "if a house".

Answer (score 3):

Consider the difference between these two statements:

> If any man leaves his platoon without express written permission of the ranking officer, he shall be shot for desertion.
>
> If a man has more than he needs, let him share it with one who has less.

The first one might be paraphrased, "*It doesn't matter who you are*, if you violate this rule, you're dead."  The rule applies to everyone.

The second one might be paraphrased, "*If there is someone who has more than he needs,* let him share with someone who has less than he needs."  The exhortation  applies to no one in particular.